Automate native Woocomerce product export
Think my logic may be skewered.
But I would like to automate the existing Woocomerce product export and save the file to a directory on a daily basis.
Ive attempted a couple avenues .i.e writing a custom php script that calls the attributes and other fields, but hit a bottle neck of the Attributes not displaying on csv.
WP-cli, however Woocom cli functionality doesnt honor how the GUI exported formats fields and either leaves key data out or interprets differently, I can rectify by creating a python script but before going down that road I was wondering if their an easier way Ive missed to trigger a cron execute this task.
I know their are few export plugins than can achieve this goal but preferably training to avoid a paid solution.
Thanks in advance.
